# Check if every single value of a dataframe column contains a value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with column `Description` that have values for example: `Anna xxxxxx` or `xxxJohnxxx`

I have then list of names:

`participants = ['Anna', 'John', 'Belle', 'David']`

I want to check whether every single values of this dataframe column contains a name in list `participants`and it should be returned as `True` or `False` for me to pass in an `if` clause. How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can craft a regex for [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and aggregate with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

Assuming this dummy input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['Anna xxxxxx', 'xxxJohnxxx', 'yyy']})
participants = ['Anna', 'John', 'Belle', 'David']
```

You can use:

```
regex = '|'.join(participants)
df['description'].str.contains(regex).all()
```

Output: `False`

Intermediate result:

```
df['description'].str.contains(regex)

0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: description, dtype: bool
```